# How to avoid someone using the "sudo" command to get unauthorized root access to my computer?

Tags: sudo, system

After understanding, what 'sudo' command does, I want to protect my computer from someone who wants to use this command for illegal purposes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't add the specific user you don't want to give `sudo` access to `sudo` group.

`sudo` uses the configuration file `/etc/sudoers` and all files under directory `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

By default, the line in `/etc/sudoers` that dictates this behavior is:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Means all users of the `sudo` group can execute any command as any user on the system.

For legacy's sake there is a line for `admin` group too:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

which is mostly unused nowadays.

So by default, unless you add the user to the `sudo` group, the user won't be able to execute commands using `sudo`.

Comment: And he should not be in `/etc/sudoers`...

Comment: By default the user created when installing the system can run sudo.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, that user is automatically added to `sudo` group.. The question implies what to do on a installed system..